# Issue with rating formating on Ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, rating

Rating Not Showing properly in Chrome (Ipad)

I have used asp.net defalt rating control. Its works perfectly in all browsers with no
compatibility issues. But its no doing fine in

Ipad -> Installed Chrome

Here is my CSS

```
.Star {
    background-image: url("/Images/rating/Star.gif");
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}
```

Below is screeshot how it looks in Ipad

[image]

thanks

Comment: do rating uses span or inline element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rating control you using will be using span with height & Width i think as span element is an inline element in HTML. You can't specify a `width` and `height` for an inline element.So

Add `display: inline-block;`

```
.Star {
    background-image: url("/Images/rating/Star.gif");
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    display: inline-block; /* or display block */
}
```

I hope this will work.

good luck!